# how do i fix: near ''~'' syntax error in SQLite

Tags: sqlite, syntax-error

I want to update a column in a table that has a numeric and non numeric data. I want to update the non numeric data to null with this queries:

```
UPDATE Employee_Performance, 
SET Employee_Satisfaction_Score = NULL, 
WHERE NOT (Employee_Satisfaction_Score ~ '^[0-9]+$');
```

I expect the Non numeric data to change to Null, but I'm having this error:
near ''~'' syntax error in SQLite

Comment: Are you sure that SQLite has a `~` operator? Maybe you want to use the `REGEXP` keyword instead.

Answer (score 0):

Your query seems to have a bunch of errors. I have no experience in SQLite, so can only tell from the documentation.

https://www.sqlite.org/lang_update.html

The problems I see in your query:

- The comma after the table name seem unnecessary
- The comma after `NULL` is also unnecessary
- The whole `WHERE` condition reads a bit awkward.
- The `~` operator: What are you trying to do using this "bitwise negation" operator?? I'm guessing that you want to use `REGEXP` here.
  https://zetcode.com/db/sqlite/expressions/

Try it this way:

```sql
UPDATE Employee_Performance
SET Employee_Satisfaction_Score = NULL
WHERE Employee_Satisfaction_Score NOT REGEXP '^[0-9]+$';
```